# Selenium clicking a button

Tags: selenium

I am trying out selenium for the 1st time and I have a quick question. When I call the `click()` method on a `WebElement`, I noticed that it is a `void` type method. So does the `HtmlUnitDriver` hold the updated page that is rendered after the `click()` happens?

Comment: No, it just clicks the element and it does not hold any info.
let us know your exact requirement.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to navigate a webpage. So how would I say 'click a button on pageA', that action loads pageB, click a button on pageB, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The `WebDriver` interface is controlling the browser, however it's still the browser (in your case, HtmlUnit) that does most of the work and remembers the state of teh page etc.

Therefore, `WebDriver` as such doesn't really have a state (an overly simplified statement, but true for your purpose). When you send a `click()` command, it performs it in the browser, than waits for the browser to complete its job (load the new page), then again waits for your commands on the new page.

`WebDriver` always operates on what the browser currently has.

Comment: I see. So when I call click(), if that takes me to another page(B), then when I say driver.findElement(By.id("whatever")), its going to search page B for that element?

Comment: @user1154644 Yes, exactly! Also, the best way to find out is to try it out ;).

Comment: Ok, so as far as javascript is concerned, is there a reason why I can navigate to a webpage and click a few buttons just fine, and get the desired results(Using Firefox), but when I use Selenium, I get javascript errors?

Comment: @user1154644 Without seeing the errors, no. Usually, though, the `HtmlUnitDriver` is less stable javascript-wise, because it uses a different JS engine than any other browser (Rhino) and therefore nobody optimizes nor tests for it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see from your question that you are using HtmlUnitDriver. JavaScript is disabled in this driver by default (for explanation [click here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver)). This driver uses the Rhino JavaScript engine and is not used in any of the popular browsers. This might explain why the actions you are trying work fine in Firefox but not in Selenium.

You could try enabling JavaScript in HtmlUnit as follows:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

**But instead I would recommend using FirefoxDriver.**

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

This should emulate the behavior you're seeing when you navigate through the webpages yourself.